# Removing an element from the array in MongoDB through mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've defined a MongoDB model using mongoose in my NodeJS application as:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const userSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
rToken: [String]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Every rToken is unique. I want to remove an element from the rToken array specified by the user in the request body, therefore, I've created a route below:

```
module.exports.logout = async (req, res) => {

const token = req.body.token;

User.updateOne({}, {$pull: {$in: [token]}});    

res.sendStatus(204);
}
```

But it isn't removing the element and I'm still getting 204 status. Please help.

Comment: Please don't provide source code as image, but as text.

Answer (score 0):

If rToken is an object you can remove element like that, assuming you remove a password key:

```
const { password, ...rTokenWithoutPassword } = rToken;
```

Then use rTokenWithoutPassword to do anything.

If you want to remove more than one key, salt and password for example:

```
const { password, salt, ...rTokenWithoutPassword } = rToken;
```

If you need to remove from within mongoDB, assuming rToken is an array of strings, you need to modify your Mongoose model because actually it is a String, not an array.

Then, according to mongodb documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Modify your update request, assuming "abcd" is the value to pull off:

```
User.updateOne({}, { $pull: { rToken: { $eq: 'abcd' } } });
```

Here is a playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fq-bH7vBUF7

Comment: I want to where am i wrong while using methods to remove the element from the array.

Comment: @Sachin In your model you declare rToken as a String, not as an array.
in mongo $pull operate with array, not strings. So if you use strings and want to remove a ke from rToken (assuming it is really an array) you can use my solution, prior to update the field in MongoDb

Comment: Now, I've modified my model to rToken: [ { type: String } ]. Also, I'm using the following line in the route to delete the element: User.updateOne({}, {$pull: {rToken: { $in: [ token ] }}}); But still it isn't working

Comment: Can you add the rToken example

Comment: rtoken will be array storing strings like ["abcd", "defg", "ghij"]

Comment: And you want to remove "abcd" for exmaple ?

Comment: Try with `{ $pull: { rToken: { $eq: 'abcd' } } }`

Comment: I updated my response, is that ok for you?

Comment: It still isn't working!

Comment: Are you shure? I've give it a try here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fq-bH7vBUF7

Comment: I still have rToken defined as-> rToken: [String]. Do I have to change this?

Comment: Yes of course, because $pull act on array, not on Strings

Comment: Okay, so what should be the syntax to define that array in the schema

Comment: It is working now, the problem was I forgot to put the await keyword before the statement. 

Comment: Well done! Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer